# Unable to update array in python in gradient descent algorithm

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, gradient-descent

In this code I have produced a dataset using gaussian distribution and then I have tried to apply stochastic gradient descent
In each iteration, I am updating the theta array. But, it is not getting updated.
It remains zero after every iteration.
Gradient is non zero. But still, theta is not updated

Help me please

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd 
# data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generating random samples

theta=np.array([3,1,2])

    

X=[]
E=[]
Y=[]
a1=3
v1=4
a2=-1
v2=4
v3=2


for i in range (0,1000000):
    x1=(1/math.sqrt(2*3.14*v1))* math.exp(-(random.random()-a1)**2/(2*v1))
    x2=(1/math.sqrt(2*3.14*v2))* math.exp(-(random.random()-a2)**2/(2*v2))
    X.append([x1,x2])
    e=(1/math.sqrt(2*3.14*v3))* math.exp(-(random.random())**2/(2*v3))
    y=theta[0]+theta[1]*x1+theta[2]*x2 + e
    Y.append(y)
    E.append(e)


#Now Applying Stochastic Gradient
##Batch_Size = 1
r=1
learning_rate=0.001
theta=np.array([0,0,0])


theta = theta.reshape(3,1)

X= pd.DataFrame(X,columns=['X1','X2'])
Y=pd.DataFrame(Y,columns=['Y'])
Y.head()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=40,random_state=50)

X_train['X0']=np.ones(len(X_train))
y_train.head()

def gradient_descent(x,y,theta,lr):
    m=len(y)
    prediction=(x.dot(theta)).to_numpy()
    gradient = prediction-y.to_numpy()
    current_cost= (1/2*m)*np.sum(np.square(prediction-y.to_numpy()) )
       
    return gradient,current_cost

n_iterations=1000
import random
theta_history=[]
cost_history=[]
for i in range(0,n_iterations):
    
    xi=X_train.sample(r)
    yi=y_train.sample(r)
    
    
    m=len(xi)
    gradient,current_cost= gradient_descent(xi,yi,theta,learning_rate)
    theta[0]= theta[0]-learning_rate* 
    ((1/m)*np.sum(np.multiply(gradient,xi['X1'].to_numpy().reshape(m,1))))  
    theta[1]= theta[1]-learning_rate* 
    ((1/m)*np.sum(np.multiply(gradient,xi['X2'].to_numpy().reshape(m,1))))
    theta[2]= theta[2]-learning_rate* 
    ((1/m)*np.sum(np.multiply(gradient,xi['X0'].to_numpy().reshape(m,1))))
    print("theta=",theta)
    
    theta_history.append(theta)
    cost_history.append(current_cost)
    
    
    
    if prev_index>=len(X_train):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You reassigned `theta` on line 34 to empty values: `theta=np.array([0,0,0])`